# Laravel 5.2 with Entrust - not able to check Permission and render 403

Tags: php, laravel-5, entrust

I'm new to Laravel and I'm developing an application with User, Roles ans Permission. For this I'm using Zizaco/Entrust. I'm almost done with all of the steps but I'm not able to show the custom page for 403. My code are as follows :

```
Permission : role-list
Role : Manager
```

`'role-list'` is assigned to '`manager'` role and then `'manager'` role is assiged to 'ABC' user.

In my app\kernel file id added these middlewares :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Eybos\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \Eybos\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
        'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
        'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
    ];
```

In my routes file :

```
Route::get( 'backend/roles', [ 'as' => 'backend.roles.index', 'uses' => 'Backend\RoleController@index', 'middleware' => ['permission:role-list|role-create|role-edit|role-delete']] );
```

And then created a file : `resources/views/errors/403.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.backend')

@section('content')
    <h1>You don't have permission.</h1>
@endsection
```

But when I try to access the page I get this error  :

```
FatalErrorException in Decorator.php line 80:
Trying to clone an uncloneable object of class Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right answer, but...

Go to Lewis->presenter->src->Decorator.php

on line 80 you should see "$object = clone $object;"

Comment that line out and it should start working with the permissions.